# How to extend CassandraRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

How do I extend CassandraRepository in spring-data-cassandra?
I've tried so many different combinations to get this to work, eventually I ended up with below.

User.java

```
@Table(name = User.TABLE)
public class User {
  private static final String TABLE = "user";

  @PartitionKey
  private UUID id;

  @Column
  private String name;

  // Getter setter methods
  ...
}
```

CassandraRepositoryCustom.java

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CassandraRepositoryCustom<T> extends CassandraRepository<T> {
  public T save(T t, Options options);
}
```

CassandraRepositoryImpl.java

```
public class CassandraRepositoryImpl<T> 
 extends SimpleCassandraRepository<T, MapId> 
 implements CassandraRepositoryCustom<T> {

  public CassandraRepositoryImpl(CassandraEntityInformation<T, MapId> metadata, 
                                 CassandraOperations operations) {
    super(metadata, operations);
  }

  @Override
  public T save(T t, Options options) {
    ...
  }
}
```

UserRepositoryCustom.java

```
public interface UserRepositoryCustom extends CassandraRepositoryCustom<User> {
  User findById(UUID id);
}
```

UserRepositoryImpl.java

```
public class UserRepositoryImpl 
 extends CassandraRepositoryImpl<User> 
 implements CassandraRepositoryCustom<User> {

    public UserRepositoryImpl(CassandraEntityInformation<T, MapId> metadata, 
                              CassandraOperations operations) {
      super(metadata, operations);
  }

}
```

UserDao.java

```
@Component
public class UserDao {

  @Autowired
  private UserRepositoryCustom repo;

  public save(User user, Options options) {
    repo.save(user, options);
  }

  public getUser(UUID id) {
    repo.findById(id);
  }

}
```

CassandraConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = CassandraRepositoryImpl.class)
public class CassandraConfig {
  ...
}
```

Now all I'm met with is the following exception

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepositoryCustom': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property save found for type User!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize Spring Data repositories in two ways:

1. Adding one or more custom methods to all repositories
2. Adding one or more custom methods to single repositories

From the code above I'm deducing that you're trying to add methods that should be available for multiple repositories. The [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour) contains a guide how to customize single repositories.

### Adding one or more custom methods to *all* repositories

Adding a method to all repositories requires you to follow four steps. This approach is handy if you want to provide a generic method that can be accessed from multiple repositories, such as your example with `save(T, Options)`.

1. Adding a base class that extends `SimpleCassandraRepository` containing the methods you're planning to expose.

   ```
   public class MyCustomizedCassandraRepository<T>
                               extends SimpleCassandraRepository<T, MapId>
                               implements MyCassandraRepository<T> {

       public MyCustomizedCassandraRepository(CassandraEntityInformation<T, MapId> metadata,
                                                       CassandraOperations operations) {
           super(metadata, operations);
       }

       public T save(T entity, WriteOptions options) {

           System.out.println(String.format("Called MyCustomizedCassandraRepository.save(%s, %s)", 
                                                entity, options));
           return entity;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Configure the base class in `@EnableCassandraRepositories`

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   @EnableCassandraRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = MyCustomizedCassandraRepository.class)
   public class DemoApplication {
       // ...
   }
   ```
3. Now create an interface that declares the method you're exposing. Doing so allows you rather extend from the base interface instead of declaring the method on each repository but that's totally up to you.

   ```
   @NoRepositoryBean
   public interface MyCassandraRepository<T> extends CassandraRepository<T> {

       /**
        * Customized save method.
        */
        T save(T entity, WriteOptions options);
   }
   ```
4. Declare your repository interfaces by extending your base interface

   ```
   interface UserRepository extends MyCassandraRepository<User> {
   }
   ```

There are no strict rules regarding naming. The important bits are setting `repositoryBaseClass` in `@EnableCassandraRepositories` and method name/parameter type convergence between the base method and the repository interface method.

I created a runnable example that customizes the repository base class. Find the link at the end of this post.

#### Remarks

The code from above neither compiles (because of `public UserRepositoryImpl(CassandraEntityInformation<T, MapId> metadata`) nor it leads to `PropertyReferenceException`.

See also:

- [Reference Documentation: Custom implementations for Spring Data repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations)
- [Runnable Example Code](https://gist.github.com/mp911de/7ff8557176fa1d78df1c0f00fec2d877)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still running into issues.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible test case (Github Repo or Gist).

Comment: Got you, I'll provide one and also update the question here

Comment: I have a repo here: https://github.com/kalypzo/example-spring
And a gist here: https://gist.github.com/kalypzo/5dbdef83632b22e4d2e6e0686e3ed0f4

Now I'm getting

> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.repository.UserRepositoryImpl required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraEntityInformation' that could not be found.

But I need this CassandraEntityInformation to be dynamic based on the Entity.

Comment: Your example contains both, single repository and base repository customization. Move `@EnableCassandraRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = CassandraCrudRepositoryImpl.class)` from `CassandraConfig` to `Startup` and make `UserRepositoryImpl` a Pojo/remove the constructor (i.e. not extending from `CassandraCrudRepositoryImpl`). `UserRepository` is already typed to `User`. `CassandraCrudRepositoryImpl` is still instantiated with `CassandraEntityInformation` and will be wired correctly. Spring Data Repositories use proxies to route method invocations to the appropriate target.

Comment: Seems it worked, not sure why I had to put EnableCassandraRepositories in Startup vs CassandraConfig, but that definitely worked!

Comment: `@EnableCassandraRepositories` takes without any further configuration the base package of your `@Configuration` class as scanning root. Placing `@EnableCassandraRepositories` with `repositoryBaseClass` configured on `CassandraConfig` registers repositories only that are located below `com.example.config`. All other repositories get defaults applied. A possible alternative is configuring `basePackageClasses = CassandraCrudRepository.class`

Comment: Thank you @mp911de. You saved me a lot of time. I was making exact same mistake.